# compressor minify javascript to huge extent

Tags: django

I am using django compressor to minify css and javascript.

I am using ckeditor and after minification by compressor, it is still around 600 KB which is huge.

Assume that I didnt any special setting.

I think default django compressor settings will simply remove space etc from javascript. Is there any advanced setting that will reduce size of javascript like ckeditor ?

Comment: Have you followed [the documentation](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scenarios/)? how did you configure django compressor? Don't you want to download the [already minified](http://ckeditor.com/download) versions of CKE or use it's CDN?

Comment: I want to follow the best way. If we can use cdn minified versions, why compressor was build ? Why do people use it ? I am confused.

Comment: If you can, the CDN is the best way. Some good uses of the compressor are: intranets (no network access to the CDN), scripts not available on a CDN, custom scripts, ...

Comment: Thanks, I used to use cdn, just started using compressor thinkings its best. Thanks for your help bufh :)